# Excel vba copy and paste the entire range with criteria?

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for reading my questions.

I have a table [ws1(A4:Q500)] contains data, while there are formula after column Q. Therefore I cannot copy the whole row but only certain range in text.

Column Q is the formula to define whether the data falls into period, i.e. 16/11-30/11 data. The flag is as follows:

> 0 < 16/11
>
> 1 = 16/11 - 30/11
>
> 2 > 30/11

Here the goal is to copy ws1 data with flag "1" to [ws2(A2:P200)]
And then delete ws1 data with flag "1" and "2"

Believe that the rules for copying and deleting is quite similar, I tried to do the copy parts first

```
Sub PlotGraph()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")   

j = 2

lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
For i = 4 To lastrow

    If ws1.Cells(i, 17) = 1 Then
        ws1.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 16)).Copy
        ws2.Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 16)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                            Operation:=xlNone, _
                            SkipBlanks:=True, _
                            Transpose:=False
     j = j + 1
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The debug functions said its wrong in

```
ws1.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 16)).Copy
```

I tried hard to do modifications but it stills not work, please help me a bit :( Thanks so much.

Comment: Why not an [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx)?

Comment: I tried but it said ws2 is not active sheet...

Comment: `ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, 16)).Copy` and just paste to the beginning cell

Comment: Yo should be able to AutoFilter without regard as to what is currently the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and the calculation for a date 'window' can be incorporated with criteria (removing the need for a formula in column Q).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ws2.Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 16)).PasteSpecial` does not adequately reference the range as belonging to `ws2`. The `Cells(...)` within the range could belong to any worksheet; they have to specifically belong to `ws2`. The same goes for `ws1`.

```
ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, 16)).Copy
ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(j, 1), ws2.Cells(j, 16)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                        Operation:=xlNone, _
                        SkipBlanks:=True, _
                        Transpose:=False
```

An [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) may save you some time with a bulk value transfer.

```
Sub PlotGraph()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lr As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")

    j = 2

    With ws1
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lr, 17)) 'Range(A3:Q & lr) need header row for autofilter
            .AutoFilter field:=17, Criteria1:=1
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 16).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .Cells.Copy _
                      Destination:=ws2.Cells(j, 1)
                    'optional Copy/PasteSpecial xlPasteValues method
                    '.Cells.Copy
                    'ws2.Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    '▲ might want to locate row j properly instead of just calling it 2
                End If
            End With
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

I noticed you are using a [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) with `xlPasteValues`. If you require value-only transfer, then that can be accommodated.

Comment: Further, wanna to ask what exactly the "If Cbool..." function? Cannot understand the logic behind..Is that I can directly PasteValues next time?

Comment: The AutoFilter hides all rows that don't match the criteria. By shifting down one row to avoid counting the header, the Application.Subtotal only counts values in visible rows. If no rows are visible then the count is zero and CBool returns false. Anything else and CBool returns true. You only try and copy to the other worksheet if there is actually something to copy.

Comment: Thanks so much Jeeped~~You are so nice